# How to print the network architecture (prototxt) from solverstate file

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have both .caffemodel and .solverstate files in CAFFE. I want to print the .prototxt file. Is it possible to print the file from the .solverstate file

Comment: what happened to your `.prototxt` file??

Comment: Actually, I lost my prototxt. I changed the prototxt many time and I did not save the best one

Comment: One more thing, I save the log file`2>&1 | tee -a train.log` but it missing some layers.

Comment: ouch :O... next use version control tools (git/svn/cvs...) it will save you.

Comment: you should have the net printed in the log! **DO NOT DELETE THE LOG**. you'll see two "prototxt" in the log: one for train net and one for validation net.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have the log file. How can I recover the prototxt. If it is possible, I will edit my question. Note that, I tried to open the log file but some information is lost in the log file. It did not write whole prototxt to the log

Comment: why don't you have the whole prototxt in the log? what happened to the log?

Comment: I do not know. just missing the detail. I guest my prototxt is too long.

Comment: you are probably right, if the model is too long not everything is saved to log. you still have the log output from the net construction listing what layer produce what outputs and what is the shape of the layer, you might be able to reverse engineer some of your data from there...

Comment: Yes. I think I have only that choice. Thnaks

Answer (score 1):

No.

#### Why?

The information in `.caffemodel` and `.solverstate` concerns only trainable parameters, and **not** the net structure. Layers that has no trainable parameters (e.g., `"ReLU"`, `"Softmax"`, `"Sigmoid"` and many more) are not represented in `.caffemodel` or `.solverstate`.
This is why you **must** have `.prototxt` file describing ALL the layers and how they connect to each other.

Answer (score 1):

log file2>&1 | tee -a train.log is much more usefull for you.
Actually it contains the whole copy of prototxt, but splited on TRAIN ant TEST phases separately: layers with  `include {phase: TEST}` are excluded from TRAIN phase and vice versa.
It's not a great challenge to compose prototxt back from thees two parts.

Comment: when the prototxt is very long, the log will only show part of it.